# failed skipping objects when reading with ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

I'm writing a program that serialize a list of objects. First i'm serializing a int number that represent the number of objects written. Then i'm serializing the objects one by one. After each time i wrote something to the file I printed that number of bytes written so far.

**Example**: 4(first int), 148(int + object1), 163(int + object1 + object2), 180, 266, 291, 306, 341, 356....

I want to be able to read a certain object while using the offset.

I tried skipping 144 bytes after reading the int to reach the second object for example using skip of FileInputStream its skipping the bytes but can't read the object.

Exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at webdata.IndexReader.<init>(IndexReader.java:36)
at webdata.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I also tried skipping using the ObjectInputStream's skipBytes but it return 0(means it skip 0 bytes) so it returns the first object.

Writer:

```
            fOutStream = new MyFileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/invertedindex.ser");
            oOutsStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fOutStream);
            oOutsStream.writeInt(invIdxArr.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < invIdxArr.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(fOutStream.getByteCount());
                oOutsStream.writeObject(invIdxArr.get(i));

            }
            oOutsStream.close();
            fOutStream.close();
```

Reader:

```
        fInStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/invertedindex.ser");
        oInStream = new ObjectInputStream(fInStream);
        int size = oInStream.readInt();
        ArrayList<InvertedIndex> invIdxArr = new ArrayList<InvertedIndex>();
        long ll= fInStream.skip(144);
        System.out.println(ll);
        invIdxArr.add(new InvertedIndex((InvertedIndex)oInStream.readObject()));
        System.out.println("freq: " + invIdxArr.get(0).getFreq() + ", postingList: " + invIdxArr.get(0).getPostingList());
        oInStream.close();
        fInStream.close();
```

Also if there a different approach to read a single object from serialized file that we'll so be helpfull.

Thanks!

Comment: You can call `reset` then `flush` when writing, and then you can seek to that point (after the flush), IIRC.

Comment: You can't skip bytes/objects in an Object stream.  The way an object is built depends on the information previous to it.  You could write multiple ObjectOutputStreams, one per object and have a size before it allowing you to skip each message, or you could use a fixed width format of your own design which allows you random access.